# Android – Facebook SDK AppEventsLogger logEvent doesn't work

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-facebook, data-collection

Googling didn't help me. I'm trying to push data on Facebook dashboard via Facebook  [app events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/app-events/?locale=ru_RU)
My code is:

```
    AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this);
    logger.activateApp(this, Utility.FACEBOOK_ID);
    logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_COMPLETED_TUTORIAL);
```

So, `activateApp` works fine, but `logEvent` doesn't.
I've checked app ID and recreated it, but I have the same problem.

Comment: It's not working for me either and I've implemented it just like you did. Have you managed this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try add the next row after 'logEvent' method.

```
logger.flush();
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to  make sure you have initialized the FB successfully before you calling the logger events：

```
Facebook.sdkInitilize(Context context);
```